# BIOS hangs when SATA drive is attached, works with hotplug

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios, sata

The American Megatrends BIOS (latest version as of manufacturer) of a Shuttle XPC SH87R6 hangs at the very beginning (not even showing the CPU type) whenever a WD 3.0TB SATA harddisk is attached. It's still responsive because I get the message to enter setup after hitting del, however I does never enter setup.

What I tried so far:

- different cable
- different SATA slot on mainboard
- changing mode from SATA to IDE or RAID in BIOS
- disabled fast boot in BIOS

Enabling SATA hotplug in BIOS and using a live usb stick with gparted on it and attaching the disk before booting (waiting at GRUB) correctly detects the disk later and I can access it without issues. So the disk itself is fine, it also works in another computer.

Could it be related to the way the disk is partitioned / formatted? I can post that information later, but it roughly is a Windows drive with a system partition, a first partition for the OS, then some free unused space and another larger NTFS partition. At the moment I can't recreate the partition table as I need the data on it, but I will try that.

Comment: The more information you can provide us the better.

Comment: I don't think it's a partition issue, as that info is read later in the boot process. Either BIOS can't handle the way that disk is communicating, or can't handle some data which disk presents about itself (serial number format, ...).

Comment: True, so even the partition table or anything like that is irrelevant, correct?

Comment: @Ramhound: As the partition scheme is not relevant, is there anything else I could provide?

Comment: I never figured out the issue and used a different drive from Seagate that worked without issues.